# I am trying to read fingerprint data and save it to server . I have include reference zkemkeeper in my project .there is an error in three function

Tags: c#, fingerprint

> Error CS1061  'CZKEM' does not contain a definition for 'SetCommuTimeOut' and no accessible extension method 'SetCommuTimeOut' accepting a first argument of type 'CZKEM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BioMetrixCore   F:\New folder\BioMatrix\BioMatrix\BioMetrixCore\Utilities\ZkemClient.cs 1395    Active
>
> Error  CS1061  'CZKEM' does not contain a definition for 'SendFileByType' and no accessible extension method 'SendFileByType' accepting a first argument of type 'CZKEM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BioMetrixCore   F:\New folder\BioMatrix\BioMatrix\BioMetrixCore\Utilities\ZkemClient.cs 1400    Active
>
> Error  CS1061  'CZKEM' does not contain a definition for 'SetCommProType' and no accessible extension method 'SetCommProType' accepting a first argument of type 'CZKEM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  BioMetrixCore   F:\New folder\BioMatrix\BioMatrix\BioMetrixCore\Utilities\ZkemClient.cs 1405    Active

only these three function are  not working

```
 public bool SetCommuTimeOut(int timeOut)
    {
        return objCZKEM.SetCommuTimeOut(timeOut);
    }

    public bool SendFileByType(int dwMachineNumber, string FileName, int iType)
    {
        return objCZKEM.SendFileByType(dwMachineNumber, FileName, iType);
    }

    public bool SetCommProType(int proType)
    {
        return objCZKEM.SetCommProType(proType);
    }
```

what is missing I can't figure it out .

Comment: Are you sure you added the DLL that contains these functions? and are using the using ?

Comment: Please explain why you thought those 3 methods were present. If the methods aren't there, the compiler cannot do anything but report it as an error. Also, which package or dll did you add a reference to? From where (exactly) did you get it?